# inner join showing duplicate rows in output . it is showing data multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I want to show values table1, and values from table2 and show them together in datagridview.
But my output is showing duplicate values, rather than 2 values its showing 4 values with same values again

```
query = "select receive_bardana.bales,receive_wheat.bags from receive_bardana
        inner Join receive_wheat
        On receive_bardana.id= receive_wheat.id
          where receive_bardana.id ='1'"
```

My output is:

```
+-------+------+
| BALES | BAGS |
+-------+------+
|  100  | 1000 |
| 1000  | 1000 |
|  100  | 2000 |
| 1000  | 2000 |
+-------+------+
```

What I have stored in tables is:

```
+-----+-------+
| ID  | BALES |
+-----+-------+
|  1  |  100  |
|  1  | 1000  |
+-----+-------+
```

```
+-----+------+
| ID  | BAGS |
+-----+------+
|  1  | 1000 |
|  1  | 2000 |
+-----+------+
```

ID IS THE RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN TWO TABLES. EG. I HAVE TWO GODOWNS.
ID IS THE ID NO. OF THE GODOWN
1 FOR GODOWN1
AND 2 FOR GODOWN 2
PRIMARY KEY IS THE AUTO INCREMENT VALUE.

Comment: Show sample data, the result you get and the result you want. (And it is probably not the tables's IDs you are joining on. What do the tables contain and how are they really related?)

Comment: The query result looks fine to me. Bales 100 is related to Bags 1000 and 2000, and bales 1000 is also related to Bags 1000 and 2000. You select the related data (which is what SQL is for) and get four rows. If you want to narrow the result so that Bales 100 only matches Bags 1000 for instance, define the rule that has these two rows related but Bales 100 | Bags 2000 unrelated.

Comment: On a sidenote: `ID is a bad name for a column that doesn't uniquely identify rows in a table. Even in an example. You should fix this. Use proper names, even in your examples, so we get an idea how the tables are related. You should also tell us what the tables' unique keys are, so we get a better idea of the data you are dealing with.

Comment: A lot of dependencies, and the ids doesn't exactly define a relationship between the two tables

Comment: @gulshan kumar, how does table `receive_bardana` relate to table `receive_wheat`, is it a `1-1 relationship`, `1-* relationship` or a `*-1 relationship` or a `*-* relationship`??

Comment: you hav ID 1  for all 4

Comment: @StefanAvramovic YES.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic 1to many

Comment: @gulshankumar . . . You have a correctly formed query which is producing sensible results.  I can't figure out what your problem is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually its showing 4 rows and i want to show only 2 rows per result

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add an extra row with ID2

```
query = "select receive_bardana.bales,receive_wheat.bags from receive_bardana
        inner Join receive_wheat
        On receive_bardana.id2 = receive_wheat.id2
          where receive_bardana.id ='1'"



|ID   |  ID2 | BALES
|  1  |  1   |  100 
|  1  |  2   |  1000
+-----+------+------+

|ID   |  ID2 | BAGS
|  1  |  1   |  1000
|  1  |  2   |  2000
+-----+------+------+
```